# Looking for an anecdote / a story about two men enjoying to read sillently reading in the library while their spouses are chatting

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I am looking for a written version of an anecdote I heard as a child. Two married couples meet regularly. The women spend the evenings chatting; their husbands withdraw to the library, sipping a whisky and smoking a cigar, reading silently. Both agree that these are the nicest evenings of the week.

Comment: Are you sure that this anecdote was in the form of a written literary short story? Such things can also be oral in nature, or just a family tale.